# Getting Redis password error with rpush command Python

Tags: python, redis

I'm running the voting app used in many K8s training and all is well except I get an error on the Redis rpush command in Python.

https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app/blob/master/vote/app.py

I do get a good redis connection before I try to push:

Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=new-redis,port=6379,db=0>>>

But then I get "authentication error - invalid password" on the rpush command.

Answer (score 0):

The redis server you're using requires authentication; you would need to pass it when creating the `Redis` object:

```
redis = Redis(host=..., db=0, password='secretkey')
```

or in the Redis URL if you use `Redis.from_url`:

```
redis = Redis.from_url('redis://:secretkey@.../0')
```

Getting the connection without authentication is a quirk of the Redis protocol, since passing the password is one command among others (`AUTH secretkey`)...